# Add table dynamically to html page - table is wider than the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am working with Jquery mobile + phonegap to build a mobile app.

One of the pages in my app contains data that i need to arrange , so i chose to put it in a table.
The data is divided in a way the each server name is in the rowHeader and each two test results are in a row (each one is represented by a button inside a column.

The server number is unlimited and also the tests.
So , i chose to build this table dynamically using javascript.

```
 <body>

        <div data-role="page" id="MonitoringPage">
            <div data-role="header"  data-theme="b">
                <h4>Monitoring tests</h4>
            </div>
            <div align='center' id="tests" data-role="content" class="ui-content" >
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer"  data-theme="b">
            <h4>MyTools</h4>
        </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Here is a jsfiddle example: 
[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdwknbrv/9/)

The page looks perfect in chrome browser , but when installing the app in a mobile device the table width is higher that the screen width.

Is someone familiar with this issue or have a solution for this?

Comment: can you post a working example that shows the problem? on jsfiddle or something like that

Comment: Yes i can.
It will take a couple of minutes.

Comment: I edited the question and added the jsfiddle example

Comment: do you set the `<meta name="viewport" ..`? it doesnt seem possible on  jsfiddle, but on your actual page? because like this, the page is zoomable and will be scrollable horizontal when zoomed in. which browser are you testing it on? what is it set to?

Comment: Yeah, like that: <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi"/>

Comment: with your update from jsfiddle.net/rdwknbrv/9 i have to say that that is expected behaviour, your table is simply wider than the screen, what you can do is either make it responsive (reduce to 1 column when the width gets to small) or do something else. you have some possbilities here, but you have to change the design somehow

Comment: I want the table to fit the mobile device screen.
Do you have a way to solve it?

Comment: you can try to work with this: http://fiddle.jshell.net/rdwknbrv/22/ but for a proper solution you have to change from table to divs, because tables don't behave well with maxWidth

Comment: I think i will try it also with divs..hope it will be different.

In the jsfiddle you added, do you think it is possible to override the fontsize also?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/rdwknbrv/26/

```
table.setAttribute("data-role", "table");
```

Although you should read this and follow other attributes too.

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/tables/

Comment: Not working on mobile device.
As i said, this is the strange problem here.
It works in browser but not in mobile device.

Comment: Android.
Galaxy s2,3,4

Comment: Here: http://mobiletest.me/samsung_galaxy_y_emulator/#u=http://jsfiddle.net/rdwknbrv/6/show/

Looks good to me

Comment: Here is an updated jsfiddle..i missed something before.

http://jsfiddle.net/rdwknbrv/9/

Comment: Whatever you missed, is causing the error(styling problem)

Comment: The thing i missed is the refresh of the page to get the css of the jquery mobile.